# RxJs: Have observable triggered by 2 independent observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I have an observable named "workcentersFiltered" of type `Observable<Workcenter[]>`

When I select a plant, I can successfully filter down my workcenters with the following code - no problem:

```js
this.workcentersFiltered = this.newLineForm.get('plant').valueChanges
      .flatMap(selectedPlant => {
        return this.dataStore.Workcenters.map(workcenters => {
          return workcenters.filter(x => x.PlantNumber === selectedPlant.PlantNumber);
        });
      });
```

The problem is, I would like to narrow that array down furtherly, when an entirely different, independent observable "`'workcenter'.valuechanges`" emits a string (it is an input field - I am trying to implement autocompletion).

So the question is, how can I subscribe to `this.newLineForm.get('workcenter').valueChanges`, so that the string-values it emits can be used to furtherly narrow down the data "hidden" within `workcentersFiltered` (which is already tied to `this.newLineForm.get('plant').valueChanges`.

Does my dilemma make sense? Must I instead redo `workcenteresFiltered` as aBehaviorSubject instead, or what is the proper solution here?

***editing in more explanation***

Currently workcentersFiltered gets data from dataStore.Workcenters, when  `plant-forminput.valuechanges` emits a change, because a plant was selected. So I can narrow down all workcenters to only ones matching the chosen plant. It works fine with the code I have above.

However I would like to introduce a new operation on the sequence between plant-forminput.valuechanges and workcentersFiltered. I would like to narrow the options even further, based on the emission from workcenter-forminput.valuechanges.

So Step 1 on my UI, the user can select a plant from a dropdown and all workcenters from other plants are filtered out - this works.

Then, Step 2 is for the user to chose a specific workcenter. This is a text-input field. I want every letter typed here (which emits on workcenter-forminput.valuechanges), to further narrow down the options (for autocompletion).

I have a difficult time imagining the solution, because the newly introduced observable from step 2 (workcenter-forminput.valuechanges), is only relevant when it emits.

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand your problem. Could you try explain a bit more or different? And/or make a small marble diagram to show what you expect?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how I could make a marble diagram. I edited my post to try and explain it in a different way.

Comment: I came to realization there's really no point to keep filteredWorkcenters as an observable. Once I retrieve data from the datastore observable, I'll just store filteredWorkcenters as a normal array - not observable too. Then I can more easily work with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) for this.

I couldn't follow your full description, so I'll just present an approximate example, which you can hopefully adapt to your specific use case:

```
workcentersForPlant = this.newLineForm.get('plant').valueChanges
      .flatMap(selectedPlant => {
        return this.dataStore.Workcenters.map(workcenters => {
          return workcenters.filter(x => x.PlantNumber === selectedPlant.PlantNumber);
        });
      });

const workCenterNameChanges = this.newLineForm.get('workCenterName').valueChanges;

// combine the 2 observables, this will trigger when either observable
// changes.  Use the combined values to do the filtering by name
this.workcentersFiltered = Observable
  .combineLatest(workcentersForPlant, workCenterNameChanges$)
  .map(([workCenters, workCenterName]) => workCenters.filter(w => w.name.startsWith(workCenterName)));
```

Comment: Fantastic. Great use of combineLatest - it makes perfect sense. I realize now I was trying to achieve the impossible, without introducing a new variable dedicated for the workcenterNameChanges